# multi piping implementation . not working

Tags: c, shell, pipe

I'm implementing  multi-pipe for my shell.The problem with the code is that it doesn't print the output of my last command in the pipe to my STDOUT. Can someone help? executePipedCommands function accepts a pointer to the head of the command list

I'm inserting for example, ls|more|grep s  to my command list.

```
struct cmd_t {
int nargs, maxargs;     
char **args;        
struct cmd_t *next;
};
typedef struct cmd_t *Cmd;
 void executePipedCommands(Cmd command) {

    int numPipes = -1;
    Cmd temp = command;
    int status;
    int i = 0;
    pid_t pid;

    while(command!= NULL)
    {   
        numPipes ++;
        command = command->next;
    }
    printf("number of pipes : %d",numPipes);


    int pipefds[2*numPipes];

    for(i = 0; i < (numPipes); i++){
        if(pipe(pipefds + i*2) < 0) {
            perror("couldn't pipe");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }


    int j = 0;
    while(command) 
    {
        pid = fork();
        if(pid == 0) 
        {

            //if not last command
            if(command->next)
            {
                if(dup2(pipefds[j + 1], 1) < 0)
                {
                    perror("dup2");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
            }

            //if not first command&& j!= 2*numPipes
            if(j != 0 )
            {
                if(dup2(pipefds[j-2], 0) < 0)
                {
                    perror(" dup2");///j-2 0 j+1 1
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

                }
            }


            for(i = 0; i < 2*numPipes; i++)
            {
                    close(pipefds[i]);
            }

            if( execvp(*command->args, command->args) < 0 )
            {
                    perror(*command->args);
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
        else if(pid < 0)
        {
            perror("error");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        command = command->next;
        j+=2;
    }
    /**Parent closes the pipes and wait for children*/

    for(i = 0; i < 2 * numPipes; i++){
        close(pipefds[i]);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < numPipes + 1; i++)
        wait(&status);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code steps through the linked list, starting at `command` and stopping when it reaches the end, in order to count the number of pipes needed.  Unfortunately, you don't reset the list back to the starting point, so you can't step through the list to execute the commands because you're already at the end.

You probably meant to write:

```
int numPipes = -1;
Cmd temp = command;

while (temp != NULL)
{   
    numPipes++;
    temp = temp->next;
}
printf("number of pipes: %d\n", numPipes);
```

The variable `temp` is otherwise unused.  Or you could write:

```
int numPipes = -1;
Cmd temp = command;

while (command != NULL)
{   
    numPipes++;
    command = command->next;
}
printf("number of pipes: %d\n", numPipes);

command = temp;
```